# Look up other files within a given URL

Tags: url, web-crawler, subdirectory

I wonder if the following is possible:

I have a URL and it is essentially a directory which contains a bunch of sub-directories and individual files. I can locate some of these files and sub-directories, but not all of them. How can I find out the rest?

If possible, what software and/or additional information do I need?

Another approach would be to download all the sub-directories and files contained in the given URL, if that's possible.

P.S. I don't own the server so that I cannot know the directory structure fully.

Comment: Yah, if you don't have access to the actual server, then the only thing you'll be able to see is what the host shows you. If they show you some directories/files and not others, then that's all you can get.